# How to make nested for-loop's number greater than or equal to previous for-loop's number

Tags: python, for-loop, nested-for-loop

How can I make it so that the right number is always greater than or equal to the left number?

```
for i in range(5):
  for j in range(5):
    # Right (j) should be greater than or equal to left (i)
    # i.e. j >= i should always be True
    print(i, j)
```

I tried to use: `if i > j:` but I did not know how to continue it.

Comment: Just generate the right numbers. Change the second for-loop to `for j in range(i, 5):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 basics errors:

1. the condition `i > j` stands for `i` *strict* smaller than `j`. To include equality use the relation `i >= j`
2. *left*, *right* and `i`, `j` are swapped: *left* should be `i`, *right* `j`

Then use the condition in the innermost body of the loops

```
for i in range(5):
    for j in range(5):
        if j >= i:
            print(i, j)
```

Remark: you could use also the dual relation `i <= j`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Andrej](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10035985/andrej-kesely) in the comments, you can change the second for-loop to `for j in range(i, 5)` - as shown below:

```python
# Right will not be smaller than left
if __name__ == '__main__':
  for i in range(5):
    for j in range(i, 5):
      print(i, j)
```